# Can the container background image be inherited in a child container using CSS?

Tags: css

If i have a body using a background image and a div inside the body using a set background and color, how can I override the div's style to use the body's background image? I don't want to simply set the background of the div to the image as positioning of the image will be off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't want to simply set the background of the div to the image as positioning of the image will be off.

You mean you want the body's actual background image to be visible (not just the URL being inherited) even though the `div` has a background color defined? That is not possible.

You would have to give the `div` a `background-color: transparent` to make the body's background image shine through.

Answer (score 1):

The [W3's `background-image` documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image) specifies that `inherit` is an invalid declaration for the property.

It seems redundant to post the same information as [@Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094128/can-the-container-background-image-be-inherited-in-a-child-container-using-css/5094167#5094167), but his work-around is, probably, the best non-`inherit` option available; although [Eric Meyer's 'Complex Spiral' demo](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css//edge/complexspiral/demo.html) is also an option, which combines `position: absolute;` with multiple different versions of, essentially, the same `background-image` to achieve quite an impressive 'tinted/coloured' effect.